# Convert QDate to Qstring?

Tags: c++, string, qt, date

I have trouble converting QDate to QString. See the code below:

```
cout << QString("\nBooking Date: %1").arg(QDate::toString(this->getBookingDate() &YYYY.mm.dd)
```

When I try to compile this it gives me:

```
‘YYYY’ was not declared in this scope
```

Yet the documentation says:

"Returns the date as a string. The format parameter determines the format of the result string..." and goes on to list the format strings.

I am new to Qt so if I am missing the obvious please excuse the ignorance.

Comment: Are you new to c++ also? That's `toString()` is not static, and even if it were, that's not how you would pass the format argument to it.

Comment: Hi, I am new to c++ yes. Trying to get to grips with all of this can be overwhelming but I have to push on thru :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want `this->getBookingDate().toString("yyyy.MM.dd")`. For further info, read the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdate.html#toString).

Comment: And just for the record, QDate doesn't appear to have a static toString method.

Comment: Related to this, the full documentation for date and time at http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#toString

Answer (score 3):

in PySide2 you can use this:

```
self.dateEdit.date().toString("yyyy.MM.dd")
```